# RNN loss calculation passed in on next iteration - Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a considerable amount of math that I need to work through for evaluating my neural net loss and accuracy, most of which I don't have a clue how to perform in tensorflow, due to complicated indexing challenges. My neural net consists of an RNN; due to the nature of RNNs would the performance decrease if I chose to pass in the loss/accuracy of the last iteration that I calculated outside of tensorflow and use that as the loss indicator instead of the current iteration and do all of the calculation out of tensorflow in regular python instead?

I suspect that I'd be fine as RNNs are meant to use past data to influence the future decisions, but the loss I will be passing in will have no direct relationship with the decisions that the neural net makes in the present. Thus I could have a large loss when correct present decisions are made ... This can happen anyway, but it magnifies the possibility of it occurring if I were to choose to go this direction.

Pros? Cons? of choosing to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always realized that this idea would never work with a normal DNN network (conceptually it doesn't make sense that it could ever work this way), but I thought it might work with an RNN network since I'm calculating my loss based off of the present to 30-60 iterations ago.

After I tested everything and combined it all, I now think I understand why I can’t calculate the loss outside of tensorflow … The GradientDescentOptimizer uses the structure of the loss to the variables to change the weights, since I’m directly plugging in the loss based on last iterations calculation, it doesn’t know how loss is connected to change up the weights to the variables.

The error that I got was:

```
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph for ops that do not support gradients, between variables
```

which means there is no path between any of the tf.Variable objects that I've defined and the loss tensor that I are trying to minimize, and this is because I was directly plugging in the loss. I did this on purpose, but apparently tensorflow doesn't allow it at all.